Why inconsistent keystroke mapping on Ubuntu?
I have an Ubuntu (22.04 with GNOME 42.9) system on my Oracle Cloud to which I am connecting through NoMachine on two different devices (Windows 11 and iPad).
As an example, when I enter the following three characters: Shift + 1, Shift + 2, Shift + 3
On the Ubuntu operating system, in like a web browser, I get:

When connected through Windows: !@£

When connected through iPad: 1"3


I checked the xev -event keyboard results on terminal and this is what I found (left is Windows, right is iPad):

In the above testing, my keyboard layout setting on Ubuntu was unchanged the entire time. So, my observations are:

When connected through iPad, what is getting typed into the web browser differs from what the XLookUpString from the xev terminal result is showing (except Shift+2)

For some reason, the mapping for Shift+2 seems to be different when connecting via Windows or iPad despite the keyboard layout setting in Ubuntu not changing

The timestamp for the KeyPress and KeyRelease events via iPad is the exact same for Press Shift, Press 1, Release 1, Release Shift, but via Windows it is not the same, each event happens a little after the other


What is going on here, and how can I fix this? This is just one example of the issue. As of right now, via iPad I haven't found a way to enter the symbols (like !,@,£,% etc) and also Shift + Alphabet is not capitalizing the alphabet (although again in the XLookUpString result from the xev terminal command, it shows the capital letter).

Cross-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/787441/why-inconsistent-keystroke-mapping-on-ubuntu

In so many words, it seems that the RDP client's keyboard settings get applied. Probably file a bug.
